# .match() is including everything, not only the caturing groups (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to parse a robots.txt file and I want to get everything between the characters: `User-agent:` and `\n`, I'm using the following regex:

```
/User-agent: (.*)\n/g
```

This regex's only capturing group is (.*) which captures every character except newline, but when I run:

```
var exampleString = 'User-agent: example\n'
var matches = exampleString.match(/User-agent: (.*)\n/g);
```

`matches[0]` is `User-agent: example\n`. Shouldn't the match return only the capturing groups instead of everything in the regex? I also tried using non capturing groups like this: `/(?:User-agent: )(.*)(?:\n)/g` and the same thing happen.

**How can I capture only the name after `User-agent:` and before `\n`?**

Comment: What you see is normal match() behavior. Please [RTFM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

Comment: `/User-agent: (.*)\n/g.exec(exampleString)` returns an array `[ "User-agent: example ", "example" ]`

Comment: Did any of these answers solve your issue?  If so, please mark the best answer as the accepted answer by checking the green checkmark to the left of that answer to indicate to the community that your question has been answered and then both you and the person who provided the answer will earn some reputation points that can lead to more privileges here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [RegExp object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec), its exec method. In that way:

```
var matches = new RegExp(/User-agent: (.*)\n/g).exec("User-agent: example\n")
```

`matches[0]` contains the full string, in this case "User-agent: example\n",
`matches[1]` contains the first capturing group so "example".

If you have more the one capturing group, you have a new value in the matches array, starting from 1.

Comment: In what way would *RegExp*.exec be superior to *String*.match?

Comment: You need to add extra \ to escape the \n

Comment: @Touffy as you can read [on the manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) (that you linked), if the g flag is set _String.match_ does not return capture groups.

So there are 2 options, OP can remove the g flag (only if he can) and use String.match, otherwise he can only use the RegExp object

Comment: Thank you. It's helpful to write that kind of explanation when you make a claim about what "should" be used :) Also — why not use a regex litteral? (I mean, you do use one, but it's wrapped in a RegExp constructor, which seems redundant)

Answer (score 0):

When using the `g` flag, the results of `.match()` are not the same as without the `g` flag.  This is because you have one returned array, but too many things to put in it with the `g` flag.  So, `.match()` chooses to not return the captured group matches, only all the multiple full matches.

From [MDN's page on `.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

> If the regular expression includes the g flag, the method returns an
>   Array containing all matched substrings rather than match objects.
>   Captured groups are not returned.

The way to get all the captured groups is to use a loop with `.exec()`:

```js
var exampleString = 'User-agent: example\n';
var re = /User-agent: (.*)\n/g, match, matches = [];
while (match = re.exec(exampleString)) {
    matches.push(match[1]);
}
document.write(JSON.stringify(matches));
```

---

Of course, since you don't actually have multiple matches in the string you show, you can perhaps simplify your solution by removing the `g` flag from the regex and then you can get captured groups with `.match()`.

```js
var exampleString = 'User-agent: example\n'
var matches = exampleString.match(/User-agent: (.*)\n/);
document.write(JSON.stringify(matches));
```